# Extracting and aggregating Hour from DateTime and Formatting the hour with AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column containing Datetime2 and need to extract, aggregate, and format the hour so that it has AM/PM.

The following table shows Customer visits during daily hours:
I need to group the hour so that all of the time in the 1pm range is aggregated.

Before processing:

```
CustomerID  Arrival
1           1:15 PM
2           1:20 PM
3           1:30 PM
4           2:00 PM
5           2:05 PM
6           2:13 PM
```

*I need the output to look like the below format:
Note: The hourly visit is the total customer visiting in an hour range. So 3 customer
visited in the 1pm hour and 3 visited in the 2pm range.*

```
HourlyVisit Arrival
3           1:00 PM
3           2:00 PM
```

I tried this code, I get the hours and it's aggregated but I need to put the hour into a more readable format.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT CustomerID = COUNT(CustomerID), 
  HourlyFrequency = DATENAME(HOUR, Arrival)
  FROM MySchema.MyTable
  GROUP BY Arrival
  )

  SELECT HourlyVisit = SUM(CustomerID), HourlyFrequency
  FROM CTE

  GROUP BY HourlyFrequency
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @AdamWenger: I have added that to the question, it was labeled as; After.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  CustomerCount = COUNT(*)
        , ArrivalHour = STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Arrival, 100), 7), 4, 2, '00 ')
FROM    MySchema.MyTable
GROUP BY STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Arrival, 100), 7), 4, 2, '00 ');
```

Comment: Kevin: I am getting 0:00 PM at the 12 PM hour.

Comment: @Unaverage_Guy you are right...  edited my answer, let me know if it works better.

Comment: Kevin: I modified it like this:

`WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  CustomerCount = COUNT(*),
ArrivalHour = STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Arrival, 100), 7), 4, 2, '00 ')
FROM MySchema.MyTable
GROUP BY Arrival
)

SELECT NumberOfVisit = SUM(CustomerCount), ArrivalHour 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ArrivalHour
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are date time, you should be able to grab the hour, and group by using [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, Arrival)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT CustomerID = COUNT(CustomerID), 
  HourlyFrequency = DATENAME(HOUR, Arrival)
  FROM MySchema.MyTable
  GROUP BY Arrival
  )

  SELECT CustomerID = SUM(CustomerID), RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), DATEADD(hour,CAST(HourlyFrequency AS INT),0), 22), 11)
  FROM CTE

  GROUP BY HourlyFrequency
```

I think this should work for you, but you should probably attempt to do this type of manipulation on the client side.